# How can I set the Accept Header for a link on a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, http

This is mostly an ivory tower question, since I can easily just make a new URL endpoint.  But basically, I'd like to be able to serve up CSV when the user has the Accept header configured to include text/csv.  That's trivial on the server side, but on the client side I don't know how to set the Accept header unless I'm using XHR or some other "non-browser" client.  Is there a way in HTML to set the Accept header in a link or in JS to set the Accept header when using window.location?

Comment: +1, this would be a good use of the protocol features.  Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to get the browser to set what it accepts on a normal link.

Comment: That's what I figured @Brad.  Doesn't hurt to ask though :)

Comment: I think this is a HTML defect. If we would be able to set the accept and accept-language headers on the HTML links, life would be much easier. E.g. you would not need to put that info into the URL to make the content cacheable, crawlable, etc... Sharing links would be much harder though...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I figure I might as well put this here for the next thousand people looking at the post.  You cannot do it.

Comment: It's sorta funny to me that anyone thinks that answer has anything to do with this question.  It works, for a different question.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**

I will leave my original answer below for posterity, but I now see that I didn't really answer the question. There isn't a way to do this "natively", the best approach I can think of would be to use a data uri (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and have AJAX do the work for you:

```
// aware that you didn't mention jQuery, but you can do this with or without
var download = function(){
    var mime = this.getAttribute('data-mime-type');
    $.ajax({
        accepts: mime,
        success: function(data){
            var uri = 'data:'+mime+';charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
            window.location = uri;
        }
    })
    return false;
}
```

With the same idea used in the example below:

`<a href="/some-csv-endpoint" data-mime-type="text/csv">Download CSV</a>`

`document.querySelectorAll('a[data-mime-type]').onclick = download;`

---

**Original Answer**

There is no built-in way to force an 'Accept' header on a link (via HTML or Javascript). I think you could pull this off fairly easily using a very small amount of server & client-side code though. Should be easy in any language, my example is PHP:

```
function get_accepted_headers() {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    if(array_key_exists('Accept', $headers)) {
        $accepted = explode(',', $headers['Accept']);
        return $accepted;
    }
    return array();
}
```

Add a data-accept attribute to your download links:

`<a href="/some-csv-file.csv" data-accept="text/csv">Download CSV</a>`

Then attach a click event handler to ensure that the user accepts the specified content type:

```
// will end up with something like: ["text/html", "application/xhtml+xml", "application/xml;q=0.9", "image/webp", "*/*;q=0.8"]
var user_headers = <?=stripslashes(json_encode(get_accepted_headers()))?>;
var click_header_check = function() {
    var accept = this.getAttribute('data-accept');
    if(user_headers.indexOf(accept) == -1) {
        console.log('User does not explicitly accept content-type: %s', accept);
        return false;
    }
    window.location = this.href;
    return;
}

// attach the event listener
document.querySelector('a[data-accept]').onclick = click_header_check;
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but hope that it helps.

Comment: Yeah, as far as I can tell this doesn't answer the question at all, since the stuff in the fake Accept don't get sent to the server.  IE to be clear, I want to OVERRIDE what the browser says

Comment: I suppose I was confused about the question, it appears you want a link to send a different request header and that isn't possible outside of using an XMLHttpRequest and using `window.location` to 'redirect' user to a `data:...` url

Answer (score 3):

For those still interested, there is a way to do this in pure javascript.

The following code uses JQuery (https://jquery.com/) and FileSaver.js (http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js/blob/master/FileSaver.js) though you could write the respective parts yourself:

```
//in case of non binary data use:
var type = 'text/xml';
var url = 'http://your_url_here/'
$.ajax({accepts:{text:type},
        url:url,
        processData:false, 
        dataType:'text', 
        success:function(data){             
                saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: type}),'filename.txt');                                                                  
            }, 
        error: function(){
               // Handle errors here
            }
    });
```