# html to make a web page return csv version

Tags: html

I have a web page which can return one of 3 versions: html, json, csv. The default is html.

If I use `curl -H "Accept: text/csv" «url»` then it returns the csv version, so the server is supporting this. However I can not figure out how to create a link in a html page, to cause the site to download the csv version of this page.

So how do I create a link to a page, such that the page sent is the csv version?

Comment: Browsers don’t really support it, but there are a couple of hacks available to get you there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361216/how-can-i-set-the-accept-header-for-a-link-on-a-web-page

Answer (score 0):

I added a query string to url `old_url?csv`. I needed to make a small change on the server. It does not scale as well, as I have to apply this hack to each page that needs it.

## What I did on the server

I edited the code for the page, if the page detects the query string `cvs`, it does not offer the server the option of the other formats.

```
if ( req.query.csv === undefined ){
    provides("html", function() {
        var template = "table";
        
        return Mustache.to_html(ddoc.templates[template],  myLib.addIfdef(Stash()), ddoc.templates.partials);
    });

    provides("json", function() {
        return JSON.stringify(Stash());
    });
}

provides("csv", function() {
    const stash= Stash();
    var store=new myLib.CsvOutputStore();
    
    store.WriteLine ([stash.title]);
    store.WriteLine (stash.head);
    store.WriteLines (stash.body);
    store.WriteLine (stash.foot);
    return store.Result();
});
```

If anyone sees a more elegant solution, then please add an answer.