# Adding an HTTP Header to GET Request hyperlink JSP page

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to add an authorization header on an http request from a JSP page, I can access the response header that i've got here on variable t, now i need to pass this token when i click the "/test" hyper link. How would i do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%
String t=response.getHeader("token");
System.out.println(t);
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Home page</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to home page, Logged in as ${UserName}</h1>

<p><a href="/test">Test</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do like this -> `<a href="/test?token=<% out.println(t); %>">Test</a>` and get the parameter using `request.getParameter("token")`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to pass it as a header, not a parameter

Comment: Hi , check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361216/how-can-i-set-the-accept-header-for-a-link-on-a-web-page) post .. you cannot do that by link but may be with js.